# Issue with MySQL delete and inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need to create a query to delete `cfc_registration` that have an old `cfc_tournament`.

**My query :**

```
delete from cfc_registration
inner join cfc_tournament on cfc_tournament.id = cfc_registration.cfcTournamendId
where cfc_registration.cfcTournamentId = cfc_tournament.id and cfc_tournament.createdAt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

**Issue :**

```
#1064 - 'inner join cfc_tournament on cfc_tournament.id = cfc_registration.cfcTournamendI' à la line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your `DELETE FROM` at start.
You should use `DELETE t1 FROM table t1` since you are specifying what you want to delete. This is implemented this way in MySQL, because you could delete records from both tables at once.

I believe this should work:

```
DELETE t1
FROM cfc_registration t1
  INNER JOIN cfc_tournament t2
    ON t2.id = t1.cfctournamendid
WHERE
  t1.cfctournamentid = t2.id
  AND t2.createdat >= date_sub( now(), interval 1 YEAR );
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer exists statement rather than inner join approach

```
delete from cfc_registration
where exists (
  select 1 from cfc_tournament 
  where cfc_tournament.id = cfc_registration.cfcTournamendId
    and cfc_tournament.createdAt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
);
```

BTW: for inner join approach, you dont need to use `cfc_registration.cfcTournamentId = cfc_tournament.id and` both on inner join and where. one is enough.

```
delete cfc_registration 
from cfc_registration
inner join cfc_tournament 
  on cfc_tournament.id = cfc_registration.cfcTournamendId
where cfc_tournament.createdAt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```